# Optimize heavy slow query in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, query-optimization, learndash

I have a fairly large database - 162150 total of rows in wp_3_posts table and 521345 total of rows in wp_3_postmeta. I noticed that my site is very slow. I noticed that the slow queries took like 10 seconds to load the page.

```
SELECT wp_3_posts.*
FROM wp_3_posts
INNER JOIN wp_3_postmeta
ON ( wp_3_posts.ID = wp_3_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( ( wp_3_postmeta.meta_key = 'course_id'
AND wp_3_postmeta.meta_value = '157898' ) )
AND wp_3_posts.post_type IN ('sfwd-lessons', 'sfwd-topic', 'sfwd-quiz')
AND ((wp_3_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_3_posts.post_status = 'future'
OR wp_3_posts.post_status = 'draft'
OR wp_3_posts.post_status = 'pending'
OR wp_3_posts.post_status = 'private'))
GROUP BY wp_3_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_3_posts.post_date DESC
```

I found out that meta_query arguments causes the page slow.

```
$attr_defaults = array(
       'include_outer_wrapper' => 'true',
       'num'                   => false,
       'paged'                 => 1,
       'post_type'             => learndash_get_post_type_slug( 'course' ),
       'post_status'           => 'publish',
       'order'                 => 'DESC',
       'orderby'               => 'ID',
       'cat'                   => '',
       'category_name'         => 0,
       'category__and'         => '',
       'category__in'          => '',
       'category__not_in'      => '',
       'categoryselector'      => '',
       'show_thumbnail'        => 'true',
       'show_content'          => 'true',
       'col'                   => '',
       'progress_bar'          => 'false',
       'array'                 => false,
       'course_grid'           => 'true',
       
       'update_post_term_cache' => false, // don't retrieve post terms
       'update_post_meta_cache' => false, // don't retrieve post meta
       'no_found_rows' => true, // counts posts, remove if pagination required 
   );
```

This is the table I am trying to optimize the meta_query arguments:

```
$enrollquery = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT Users.ID, Users.user_login, Users.display_name, Learndash.activity_type, PostObject.post_status, PostObject.post_title, PostObject.post_type FROM `wp_users` AS `Users`INNER JOIN `wp_3_learndash_user_activity` AS `Learndash` ON Users.ID = Learndash.user_id INNER JOIN `wp_3_posts` AS `PostObject` ON PostObject.ID = Learndash.post_id INNER JOIN `wp_3_postmeta` AS `Postmeta` ON PostObject.ID = Postmeta.post_id WHERE Users.ID = '".$current_user->ID."' GROUP BY PostObject.ID"));
```

Is there a way to optimize that?

Comment: There's a plugin for this problem. https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_3_learndash_user_activity` -- I suspect its indexes need improving.

Comment: Learndash table layouts described [here](https://www.learndash.com/support/docs/developers/database-info/). Lots of single-column indexes. Sigh. This is a proprietary, not open-source, plugin.

Answer (score 0):

### First

Your question's second query is this, formatted.

```sql
SELECT Users.ID, Users.user_login, Users.display_name, 
       Learndash.activity_type, 
       PostObject.post_status, PostObject.post_title, PostObject.post_type
  FROM wp_users AS Users
 INNER JOIN wp_3_learndash_user_activity AS Learndash ON Users.ID = Learndash.user_id
 INNER JOIN wp_3_posts AS PostObject ON PostObject.ID = Learndash.post_id
 INNER JOIN wp_3_postmeta AS Postmeta ON PostObject.ID = Postmeta.post_id
 WHERE Users.ID = '".$current_user->ID."'
 GROUP BY PostObject.ID
```

I think it has a mistake in it. You do an INNER JOIN from `posts` to `postmeta`,  but you don't include a `meta_key` filter. That means the query picks up all the `postmeta` rows for the post in question. That probably isn't right. It definitely makes the query handle a lot of extra data, only to have it removed by your GROUP BY.

Usually `postmeta` joins look something like this:

```sql
 INNER JOIN wp_3_postmeta AS Postmeta
        ON PostObject.ID = Postmeta.post_id
       AND Postmeta.meta_key = 'course_id'  /* or some other constant */
```

**Pro tip** always format your queries in your source code so you can read them easily. php allows multiline string constants.

### Second

According to [LearnDash's help page](https://www.learndash.com/support/docs/developers/database-info/) its table is defined

```sql
CREATE TABLE wp_learndash_user_activity (
  activity_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  post_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  activity_type varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  activity_status tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  activity_started int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  activity_completed int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  activity_updated int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (activity_id),
  KEY user_id (user_id),
  KEY post_id (post_id),
  KEY activity_status (activity_status),
  KEY activity_type (activity_type),
  KEY activity_started (activity_started),
  KEY activity_completed (activity_completed),
  KEY activity_updated (activity_updated)
)
```

That table could use a change to an index, extending the `user_id` index to [cover](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/#covering-indexes) your query.  You can do this with any MySQL client program.  **Make a backup first, and do it in a quiet time on your site**. But, unless your users each do large numbers of activities, this index probably won't help much.

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_3_learndash_user_activity
    DROP INDEX user_id,
    ADD INDEX user_id (user_id, post_id, activity_type);
```

### Third

Your indexes on `posts` and `postmeta` need changing too. There's a plugin to handle those changes. [Index WP MySQL For Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/). It creates indexes to cover queries like yours, [described here](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/tables_and_keys/#wppostmeta).

Comment: I bet LearnDash stores 32-bit UNIX timestamps in `activity_started` and similar columns. That's going to blow out in 2038.